# Issue in if/else statement iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using the below code, but I am not getting that why it is not working properly, I think my logic is incorrect.

Please take a look and suggest me the solution.

```
- (IBAction)fajarButton:(id)sender {

    name = @"f";

    NSLog(@"Selected namaz is Fajar");

    [a1 setAlpha:0]; [a2 setAlpha:0]; [a3 setAlpha:0]; [a4 setAlpha:0]; [a5 setAlpha:0];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]]; 
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"]; 
    NSString *day = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]; 

    NSLog(@"day::: %@", day);


    if ([day isEqualToString:@"Monday"]) {

        [fajarButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    }
    if ([day isEqualToString:@"Tuesday"]) {

        [fajarButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    }
    if ([day isEqualToString:@"Wednesday"]) {

        [fajarButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    }
    if ([day isEqualToString:@"Thursday"]) {

        [fajarButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    }
    if ([day isEqualToString:@"Friday"]) {

        [fajarButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    }
    if ([day isEqualToString:@"Saturday"]) {

        [fajarButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    }
    if ([day isEqualToString:@"Sunday"]) {

        [fajarButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    }
}
```

What here I am trying to do is that, say, if today is monday and this button clicked once then after it should be disabled for this day monday so that user would not click it again or whenever user clicks it an alert should come up that you have already done that. And when new day Tuesday will come and app will be started, as the new day has started now again the button will be enabled and user will be able to click it once.

How to achieve it all.... I am in much problem

Comment: is `friArray == nil` or empty ?

Comment: yeah.  or are you not getting into the conditional?

Comment: You put a different code in your question now. Better to open a new question than to modify an existing one to different code, after answers have been given to the initial question. Also your in your if statements you always do the same thing. So what's the use of the if statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your friArray is empty.

Comment: Well, first print out friArray in NSLog(@ "now we are here friday....friArray: %@",friArray);   Then if it's empty or nil, where do you think you have created it?  (Your current code shows no other reference to friArray at all.)

Comment: Well, so what's it supposed to be? Where do you create it?

Comment: Well, you created it but didn't add any items to the array so it is empty.  You need to fill it with the strings that you are looking for.

Comment: Really not clear what your goal is.  Note that your statement "Like friArray is empty then the else part should get done" is incorrect.  The else part is inside your for loop, so it won't get called unless there's something in friArray to assign to string. Please add a note to your Question, explaining what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well, I've modified your code above to do what you say, but friArray is still never getting anything added to it, and I don't know what aa4 etc are for.

Comment: Which "specific object"? If you add any of those in salahforgraph, you will get the error next time in this routine. For me to help, I really need to know what you're trying to do at a higher level. And please add relevant parts of salahforgraph.  Did my revised code help?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9793/discussion-between-mackworth-and-ierror)

Comment: hey mackworth you helped me alot.... but it is all messing-up, code does not works, now i have tried to make it in another way .... please check the edited question

Comment: @mackworth Thank you very much bro..... I am done with it.... have resolved the issue in a different way .... You really helped me alot .... :)

Comment: Glad to hear that I could be of help. I see you're going down the path of disabling buttons they've already pressed. That's good; almost always better to head off mistakes than to give error messages. I would dim the button,not just turn it off. And keep in mind Don't Repeat Yourself. When you find you are, use methods, arrays,or other techniques to express it in a more general way.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If friArray is empty, else doesn't get called because the for loop doesn't iterate. Check for empty friArray before your for loop

```
if ([friArray count] ==0) {
    //do what you do when it's empty
}
else {
    //do your for loop
}
```

Comment: thanx Mario.... but it is all messing-up. I have changed my question. I am trying to do it in another way. Please check the edited question

Comment: Okay, this is a different code now. Was the initial problem solved? Or did you dump the code and this is a new approach to what you initially wanted to achieve?

Comment: Thank you Mario ... actually previous didnt help.... And this is new approach to resolve the same issue. But now I have resolved the issue.